# Fill NaN values withont df with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups     Nb    Event    VALUE1     VALUE2    Seqs Other_colum
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq0 30
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq1 NaN
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     NaN        NaN       Seq2 49
Groupe1    4.0   12.0     0.1        2.3       Seq3 34
Groupe1    3.0   3.0      0.9601     0.825981  Seq6 67
Groupe1    3.0   3.0      0.9601     0.825981  Seq7 NaN
Groupe3    1.0   1.0      NaN        NaN       Seq4 78
Groupe3    1.0   1.0      NaN        NaN       Seq5 67
Groupe3    1.0   3.0      NaN        NaN       Seq6 89
Groupe3    1.0   3.0      0.4        0.45      Seq7 NaN
```

and I would like within `Groups` to fill `NaN` values in `VALUE1` & `VALUE2` when there is a none NaN value in corresponding `Nb`  & `Event`.

For exemple :

within Groupe1

there is

```
Groups     Nb    Event    VALUE1     VALUE2    Seqs
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     NaN        NaN       Seq2
```

then I check if corresponding `Nb` and `Event` have values in `VALUE1` & `VALUE2`, here yes the values are  : 0.2971 & 0.000000

```
Groups     Nb    Event    VALUE1     VALUE2    Seqs
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq0
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq1
```

so I add this values to the NaN values

```
Groups     Nb    Event    VALUE1     VALUE2    Seqs
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq2
```

here at the and I should get :

```
Groups     Nb    Event    VALUE1     VALUE2    Seqs Other_colum
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq0 30
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq1 NaN
Groupe1    2.0   19.0     0.2971     0.000000  Seq2 49
Groupe1    4.0   12.0     0.1        2.3       Seq3 34
Groupe1    3.0   3.0      0.9601     0.825981  Seq6 67
Groupe1    3.0   3.0      0.9601     0.825981  Seq7 NaN
Groupe3    1.0   1.0      NaN        NaN       Seq4 78
Groupe3    1.0   1.0      NaN        NaN       Seq5 67
Groupe3    1.0   3.0      0.4        0.45      Seq6 89
Groupe3    1.0   3.0      0.4        0.45      Seq7 NaN
```

And idea of an algorithm I guess would be to :

```
iterate over Groups within the table :
 then check where df['VALUE1'].isna() & df['VALUE2'].isna():
    look at the corresponding df['Event'] & df['Nb']
        if the correspond VALUE1  &  VALUE2 are not NaN
            fill the previous NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `groupby` here on `Groups, Nb, Event` then use backfill (`bfill`) and forwardfill (`ffill`) to fill your `NaN`:

```
df.groupby(['Groups', 'Nb', 'Event']).apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```

```
    Groups   Nb  Event  VALUE1    VALUE2  Seqs
0  Groupe1  2.0   19.0  0.2971  0.000000  Seq0
1  Groupe1  2.0   19.0  0.2971  0.000000  Seq1
2  Groupe1  2.0   19.0  0.2971  0.000000  Seq2
3  Groupe1  4.0   12.0  0.1000  2.300000  Seq3
4  Groupe1  3.0    3.0  0.9601  0.825981  Seq6
5  Groupe1  3.0    3.0  0.9601  0.825981  Seq7
6  Groupe3  1.0    1.0     NaN       NaN  Seq4
7  Groupe3  1.0    1.0     NaN       NaN  Seq5
8  Groupe3  1.0    3.0  0.4000  0.450000  Seq6
9  Groupe3  1.0    3.0  0.4000  0.450000  Seq7
```

---

To only fill certain columns, select these before applying your methods:

```
grps = ['Groups', 'Nb', 'Event']
values = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']

df[values] = df.groupby(grps)[values].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
# or df.groupby(grps).apply(lambda x: x[values].bfill().ffill())
```

---

Side note: in general we do not need to iterate over our data, since it will be inefficient and pandas provides methods to solve these issues.

Comment: Thank you but what if I only want to fill ```['VALUE1' ,'VALUE2'] ```and not all columns ? I Added the ```Other_column``` to illustrate